# Magento2 Catalog search result and product listing grid only sort by product name set

Tags: magento2, sorting, product-grid, toolbar, product-sorting

I need below condition to my website.

Magento2 Catalog search result and product listing grid only sort by product name to be set.

I have also back-end configuration done but
issue is like product listing page is show product name and when search any product then catalog search result page show relevant search .

so give me solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by other attribute, you need to...

- Go to: Stores > Attribute > Product
- Choose the product you want to integrate to be able to change the sort order
- Navigate to "Storefront Properties" (on the left)
- Set "Used for Sorting in Product List" to "Yes"

[image: Magento2 edit attribute properties to make is available in the sort order option]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your attribute 'Used for Sorting in Product Listing' to Yes
2. Just add this block in referenceContainer at catalogsearch_result_index.xml

> ```
> <referenceBlock name="search_result_list">
>             <action method="setDefaultDirection">
>                 <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">asc or desc</argument>
>             </action>
>             <action method="setSortBy">
>                 <argument name="attribute" xsi:type="string">attribute_code</argument>
>             </action>
> </referenceBlock>
> ```